# Inconsistant results using either Get-WMIObject or Get-CimInstance

Tags: get-wmiobject

The beginnings of a simple script to retrieve LastLogon property data from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile. Both Servers 2019 DataCenter. When I run the script targeting 2 different servers, **one server will return the LastLogon data for AD logins while the other will only return data for local logins**. Ulitimately the script will rely on LastLogon data consistantly retreived from any server. It all works as expected when run on localhost.

```
         Write-Host "Enter the name of the Server you wish to query:  "
        $Server = Read-Host
        
        Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $Server |  
Select-Object -Property LastLogon,Name
     
        #or 
        
        Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $Server |  
Select-Object -Property LastLogon,Name

Sample output from both servers :

Enter the name of the Server you wish to query:  
LON-SVR1

LastLogon                 Name                        
---------                 ----                        
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM         
                          NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  
                          NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
6/14/2021 1:02:53 PM      LON-SVR1\Administrator      
                          ADATUM\ida                  
                          ADATUM\Administrator        
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM         
                          NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  
                          NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
20210614130253.000000-420 LON-SVR1\Administrator      
                          ADATUM\ida                  
                          ADATUM\Administrator        



PS E:\mod01> .\Untitled7.ps1
Enter the name of the Server you wish to query:  
LON-DC1

LastLogon                 Name                        
---------                 ----                        
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM         
                          NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  
                          NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
6/27/2023 9:24:25 AM      ADATUM\Abbi                 
6/27/2023 12:10:53 PM     ADATUM\Ida                  
6/27/2023 1:59:25 PM      ADATUM\Administrator        
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM         
                          NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  
                          NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
20230627092425.000000-420 ADATUM\Abbi                 
20230627121053.000000-420 ADATUM\Ida                  
20230627135925.000000-420 ADATUM\Administrator
```